# Detele() - Play Framework - Compilation error

Tags: java, play-framework

#### Introdução

Estou fazendo um CRUD na minha aplicação, tudo está perfeito porém meu delete está dando erro na hora de compilar

#### Erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Task.java

```
package models;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.*;
import play.db.ebean.*;
import play.data.validation.Constraints.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Task extends Model{

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Required
    public String tarefas;

    public static Finder find = new Finder(Long.class, Task.class);

    public static List<Task> all() {
        return find.all();
    }

    public static void create(Task task) {
        task.save();
    }

    public static void delete(Long id) {
        find.ref(id).delete();
    }

}
```

#### Controller

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.data.*;
import play.data.Form;
import views.html.*;
import models.*;

public class Application extends Controller {
    static Form<Task> taskForm = Form.form(Task.class);

    public static Result index() {
        return redirect(routes.Application.tasks());
    }

    public static Result tasks() {
        return ok(views.html.index.render(Task.all(), taskForm));
    }

    public static Result newTask() {
        Form<Task> filledForm = taskForm.bindFromRequest();
        if(filledForm.hasErrors()){
            return badRequest(
                    index.render(Task.all(), filledForm)
            );
        }else{
            Task.create(filledForm.get());
            return redirect(routes.Application.tasks());
        }
    }

    public static Result deleteTask(Long id) {
        Task.delete(id);
        return redirect(routes.Application.tasks());
    }
}
```

Comment: Poderia colocar o erro em texto?

Comment: como assim erro em texto?

Comment: Em algo que não seja imagem

Answer (score 2):

Estudando o Ebean pelo [site](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/Ebean.html), notei o uso do Singleton Ebean e a rotina deveria ficar assim:

```
public static void delete(Long id) {
    Ebean.delete(Ebean.find(Task.class,id));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Troque isso:

```
public static Finder find = new Finder(Long.class, Task.class);
```

Por isso:

```
private  static Finder<Long, Task> find = new Finder<Long, Task>(Long.class, Task.class);
```

O Finder cria um localizador (find) para a entidade do tido tipo informado com o ID do tipo informado.

Você também pode tentar usar:

find.byId(id).delete();

Vêja esse exemplo: [Play 2.3.5 Master-Detail](https://github.com/Alfaville/Master-Detail-Play-Framework-2.3.5/blob/master/app/controllers/PessoasController.java)

Comment: É legal explicar, ainda que brevemente, porquê seu código resolve o problema. O guia [answer] tem mais detalhes.

Comment: OK, vou editar minha resposta.